# Convert json to array and iterate array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm using curl to receive a json object but I'm having problem to convert it and iterate it to insert in database.

I start to decode the information received:

```
$response = json_decode(curl_exec($curl), true);
```

and it return this:

`array(1) { ["d"]=> string(14033) "[{"casa":181,"id":"8892","nome":"XPTO","morada":"rua 1"}]"`

Next I access to `"d"` because I don't need that:

```
$resp =  $response["d"];
```

and it returns this:

```
"[{"casa":181,"id":"8892","nome":"XPTO","morada":"rua 1"}]"
```

How can why iterate this with `" "`?

What is the better way to do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do double decode because your curl response is double encoded, Do it this way-

```
$response = json_decode(curl_exec($curl), true);
$resp = json_decode($response['d'], true);
```

Comment: As they can already access `$response["d"]`, it looks as though you only need to decode this rather than decoding the whole thing twice.